# Language Selector configuration

Tags: mediawiki

In order to configure the LanguageSelector extension, we placed these parameters inside our LanguageSelector.php file as shown in the [manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LanguageSelector) but they don't seem to be taking effect:

[Img of configuration of LanguageSelector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yopsD.png)

```
if ( function_exists( 'wf_LoadExtension ' ) ) {

 $wgLanguageSelectorLanguages = [ 'es', 'en' ];
 $wgLanguageSelectorDetectLanguage = LANGUAGE_SELECTOR_USE_CONTECT_LANG;
 $wgLanguageSelectorLocation = LANGUAGE_SELECTOR_AS_PORTLET;

 wfLoadExtension( 'LanguageSelector' );

 $wgMessagesDirs['LanguageSelector'] = __DIR__ . '/i18n';

 return;

} else {

 die( 'This version of the LanguageSelector extension requires MediaWiki 1.35+' );

}
```

The language selector dropdown shows all the languages instead of just English and Spanish.

Any idea of what is likely to be the problem?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All extensions are configured in **`LocalSettings.php`** *after* their inclusion with `wfLoadExtension()` (there is no underscore)/`require_once()`.

So, try restoring the original `LanguageSelector.php` and then inserting into `LocalSettings.php`:

```php
wfLoadExtension( 'LanguageSelector' );
$wgLanguageSelectorLanguages = [ 'es', 'en' ];
$wgLanguageSelectorDetectLanguage = LANGUAGE_SELECTOR_USE_CONTECT_LANG;
$wgLanguageSelectorLocation = LANGUAGE_SELECTOR_AS_PORTLET;
```

Comment: These were the issues. Thank you!